# Pandas - Sum of rows between two indexes in diffrent columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two conditions.
I want to count the rows from when condtion 1 is first time hit until condition 2 is hit, then start over again and wait for the next time cond1 gets hit again and sum up til cond2

What i want to sum is the the "change" column in that span of rows between the conditions.

cond 1 indexes are = 4, 8, 12, 16

cond 2 indexes are =  10, 16, 19, 23

To sum it up i want to sum the change column from index 4 to index 10 skipping index 8, then from 12 to 16, then 16 to 19 and so forth.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randn

np.random.seed(101)
dfA = pd.DataFrame(randn(100,2),columns='A B'.split())
dfA['B'] = dfA['B']+10

def analyse(df):
    df = df.copy()
    #df['change'] = 10 for sake for simplicity this is more logical to test
    df['change'] = df.B.pct_change()
    df['cond1'] = np.where(df['A'] < -1 ,1,0)  
    df['cond2'] = np.where(df['B'] > 11, 1,0)
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    return df


print(analyse(dfA))


output sample:
           A          B    change  cond1  cond2
1   0.000357   9.565909 -0.105097      0      0
2  -0.360938  10.326678  0.079529      0      0
3   0.968598   9.536587 -0.076510      0      0
4  -1.144810   9.565296  0.003010      1      0
5   1.107228  10.781904  0.127190      0      0
...
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: i dont have an expected output,  im just trying to learn how to use pandas. but the reason is because im building a trading bot

Comment: A pandas question with a true [mre] definitely deserves a +1 ...

Comment: If you have a running index, like you seem to have in your case, find rows 1 and 2, store the index number for the row somewhere and rest is just a simple substraction of the values

Comment: There is not enough information.

The condition == 1 indexes are: 
cond1 = `4, 8, 12, 16,....`, `cond2 = 10, 16, 19, 23,`

So you need to clarify what you want to do, eg:
sum form 4 to 10,
skip 8,
sum 12 to 16,
what happens with 16 to 16? skip? or sum 16 to 23,
etc.

Comment: Can you answer to the question of @Yehla, please?

Comment: I just updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic for grouping is complicated enough so that we need to write a function to do it, so we start with that:

```
def groups_from_conditions(cond1, cond2):
    '''
    assign a unique non-NaN integer to each group as defined by the rules
    '''
    n = len(cond1)
    
    group_idx = -1
    groups = np.zeros(n)

    curr_state = 0    # 0 = not in a group, 1 = in a group
    for n in range(n):
        if curr_state == 0:
            # Currently not in a group
            if cond1[n] == 1:
                # Detected start of a group. so:
                # switch the state to 1 ie in a group
                curr_state = 1
                # get a new group_idx
                group_idx = group_idx + 1
                # assign it to the output for element n
                groups[n] = group_idx
            else:
                # no start of the group detected, we are not in a group so mark as NaN
                groups[n] = np.NaN

        else: 
            # current_state == 1 so we are in a group
            if cond2[n] == 1:
                # detected end of group -- switch state to 0
                curr_state = 0
            # as we are in a group assign current group_idx. Note that this happens for the element
            # for which cond2[n] == 1 as well, ie this element is included
            groups[n] = group_idx

    return groups
```

To see that it is doing the right thing let's apply it to the first 25 rows and observe the results

```
# calculate cond1 and cond2
df2 = analyse(dfA)

# Test our logic
test_cond1 = df2.loc[:25, 'cond1'].values
test_cond2 = df2.loc[:25, 'cond2'].values
test_groups = groups_from_conditions(test_cond1, test_cond2)

# stick in test_df for ease of printing
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'cond1' : test_cond1, 'cond2' : test_cond2, 'groups' : test_groups})
test_df
```

we obtain

```
      cond1    cond2    groups
--  -------  -------  --------
 0        0        0       nan
 1        0        0       nan
 2        0        0       nan
 3        1        0         0
 4        0        0         0
 5        0        0         0
 6        0        0         0
 7        1        0         0
 8        0        0         0
 9        0        1         0
10        0        0       nan
11        1        0         1
12        0        0         1
13        0        0         1
14        0        0         1
15        1        1         1
16        0        0       nan
17        1        0         2
18        1        1         2
19        1        0         3
20        0        0         3
21        0        0         3
22        0        1         3
23        0        0       nan
24        0        0       nan
```

we see that a unique integer id (in `groups`) is assigned to each group and it seems to satisfy the requirements

Now we can just `groupby` on the output of our function and `sum` the right column

```
df2.groupby(groups_from_conditions(df2['cond1'].values, df2['cond2'].values))['change'].sum().to_frame()
```

output

```
        change
--  ----------
 0  0.21502
 1  0.173852
 2  0.138442
 3  0.00701182
 4  0.209301
 5  0.175492
 6  0.0209937
 7  0.146636
 8  0.290243
```

### Edit -- better output

This also returns the start and the end index for each group:

```
df2.reset_index().groupby(groups_from_conditions(df2['cond1'].values, df2['cond2'].values)).agg({'change':sum, 'index':['first','last']})
```

output

```
    change      index
    sum         first   last
0   0.215020    4       10
1   0.173852    12      16
2   0.138442    18      19
3   0.007012    20      23
4   0.209301    45      46
5   0.175492    50      56
6   0.020994    57      61
7   0.146636    62      71
8   0.290243    85      99
```

Comment: thank you so much for your precise answer, this was a valuable lesson, i have gone deeper into to the world of dataframes now, i salute you!!

Comment: Python one-liners are wonderfull , in the last part of the code you write: index':['first','last']} is it possible to write other strings here for other results? what is this "thing" called i would like to read the documentation

Comment: @SomaJuice gad this helped and yes it is certainly possible to get other results out. Probably good place to start is agg docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

It took me some time to understand the logic, but `transform` can do a good job here.

If would group the dataframe by blocs ending with a 1 in the cond2 column, and transform each bloc using an auxiliary function to give the result the sum of the changes column starting with the first 1 value in cond1.

The auxiliary function is:

```
def process(f):
    x = df.loc[f.index, 'cond1'].cummax()
    val = f[x > 0].sum()
    return np.where(x > 0, val, 0)
```

We can now directly get the expected result with:

```
df = analyse(dfA)
df['changes_sum'] = df.groupby(df['cond2'].shift().fillna(0).cumsum()
                               )['change'].transform(process)
```

to get:

```
           A          B    change  cond1  cond2  changes_sum
1   0.000357   9.565909 -0.105097      0      0     0.000000
2  -0.360938  10.326678  0.079529      0      0     0.000000
3   0.968598   9.536587 -0.076510      0      0     0.000000
4  -1.144810   9.565296  0.003010      1      0     0.215020
5   1.107228  10.781904  0.127190      0      0     0.215020
6   0.113930   9.230490 -0.143891      0      0     0.215020
7  -0.186869   8.754208 -0.051599      0      0     0.215020
8  -2.016947   8.509005 -0.028010      1      0     0.215020
9   1.324123  10.621020  0.248209      0      0     0.215020
10 -0.021689  11.259448  0.060110      0      1     0.215020
11 -0.303271   9.845053 -0.125618      0      0     0.000000
12 -1.274105   9.730489 -0.011637      1      0     0.173852
13 -0.299103   9.541319 -0.019441      0      0     0.173852
14 -0.374649  10.755250  0.127229      0      0     0.173852
15  0.426690  10.450911 -0.028297      0      0     0.173852
16 -2.347033  11.558679  0.105997      1      1     0.173852
17  0.213736   9.951042 -0.139085      0      0     0.000000
18 -1.701469  10.251330  0.030176      1      0     0.138442
19 -1.485369  11.361190  0.108265      1      1     0.138442
20 -1.311128  10.514855 -0.074494      1      0     0.007012
21  1.158399   8.753032 -0.167556      0      0     0.007012
22  0.065564   9.997387  0.142163      0      0     0.007012
23  2.517158  11.066090  0.106898      0      1     0.007012
24 -0.388263   8.438005 -0.237490      0      0     0.000000
25  0.822394   8.924752  0.057685      0      0     0.000000
26  0.122491  10.624278  0.190428      0      0     0.000000
27 -0.882316   9.728327 -0.084330      0      0     0.000000
28 -0.245772  10.567543  0.086265      0      0     0.000000
29  0.172045  10.855364  0.027236      0      0     0.000000
30  1.709001   9.422214 -0.132022      0      0     0.000000
31 -0.280294   9.770575  0.036972      0      0     0.000000
32 -0.691827   9.080614 -0.070616      0      0     0.000000
33 -0.321549  10.590952  0.166326      0      0     0.000000
34 -0.155032   9.512700 -0.101809      0      0     0.000000
35 -0.052168   9.782063  0.028316      0      0     0.000000
36  0.951612   7.770738 -0.205614      0      0     0.000000
37  0.725763  11.399600  0.466991      0      1     0.000000
38  0.793190  10.718898 -0.059713      0      0     0.000000
39  2.080533  10.018371 -0.065354      0      0     0.000000
40  2.890031  11.147476  0.112703      0      1     0.000000
41  1.563451   9.316422 -0.164257      0      0     0.000000
42 -0.358973   8.371704 -0.101404      0      0     0.000000
43 -0.042927  10.443485  0.247474      0      0     0.000000
44  0.438877   9.734462 -0.067891      0      0     0.000000
45 -1.369854  10.522775  0.080982      1      0     0.209301
46 -1.260196  11.873045  0.128319      1      1     0.209301
47 -0.012729   9.267605 -0.219442      0      0     0.000000
48  0.603590   9.903244  0.068587      0      0     0.000000
49 -0.120610  10.041392  0.013950      0      0     0.000000
50 -1.372217   9.180103 -0.085774      1      0     0.175492
51 -0.068498   9.098150 -0.008927      0      0     0.175492
52  0.125410   9.040123 -0.006378      0      0     0.175492
53  0.874425   8.371506 -0.073961      0      0     0.175492
54 -0.442511   9.988561  0.193162      0      0     0.175492
55 -0.621700   9.558664 -0.043039      0      0     0.175492
56 -1.120992  11.474312  0.200410      1      1     0.175492
57 -1.458678  10.187339 -0.112161      1      0     0.020994
58  0.114353   9.922086 -0.026038      0      0     0.020994
59 -0.254377   8.413193 -0.152074      0      0     0.020994
60 -0.754028  10.927496  0.298852      0      0     0.020994
61  0.028300  11.063152  0.012414      0      1     0.020994
62 -1.768822  11.431818  0.033324      1      1     0.033324
63  0.742857   9.080574 -0.205675      0      0     0.000000
64 -1.040765   9.573166  0.054247      1      0     0.318988
65 -0.510999  10.168282  0.062165      0      0     0.318988
66  0.438022  10.404902  0.023270      0      0     0.318988
67 -0.359517   9.077677 -0.127558      0      0     0.318988
68 -0.730178   8.614026 -0.051076      0      0     0.318988
69 -0.449042  10.532863  0.222757      0      0     0.318988
70  1.003614   9.469792 -0.100929      0      0     0.318988
71  1.386934  11.705711  0.236111      0      1     0.318988
72  0.296448  11.640889 -0.005538      0      1     0.000000
73 -0.549103  11.163379 -0.041020      0      1     0.000000
74 -0.389459  10.764772 -0.035707      0      0     0.000000
75 -0.857943   8.109918 -0.246624      0      0     0.000000
76 -0.623137  10.847840  0.337602      0      0     0.000000
77 -0.397094  10.518781 -0.030334      0      0     0.000000
78 -0.874785   9.509236 -0.095975      0      0     0.000000
79  0.930555   9.490074 -0.002015      0      0     0.000000
80 -0.800944   8.843778 -0.068102      0      0     0.000000
81 -0.374924   9.377653  0.060367      0      0     0.000000
82 -0.509361   9.875481  0.053087      0      0     0.000000
83 -0.063740  10.099272  0.022661      0      0     0.000000
84  0.254932   8.432778 -0.165011      0      0     0.000000
85 -2.104728   8.578837  0.017320      1      0     0.290243
86 -0.355120   9.887398  0.152534      0      0     0.290243
87 -1.911956   9.824299 -0.006382      1      0     0.290243
88 -0.116750  10.173219  0.035516      0      0     0.290243
89  1.389123  10.281146  0.010609      0      0     0.290243
90 -0.441094  10.642809  0.035177      0      0     0.290243
91  0.686238  10.029521 -0.057625      0      0     0.290243
92  0.983907   8.541020 -0.148412      0      0     0.290243
93 -0.486963   9.527907  0.115547      0      0     0.290243
94  0.250544  10.741613  0.127384      0      0     0.290243
95  0.929991   9.916856 -0.076781      0      0     0.290243
96  0.674956   9.617204 -0.030216      0      0     0.290243
97 -0.533244   7.702358 -0.199106      0      0     0.290243
98  1.973100  10.727567  0.392764      0      0     0.290243
99  1.460717   9.889898 -0.078086      0      0     0.290243
```

Comment: Wow that is crazy few lines of code! beautifull! love the the simplicity of it!

Comment: i just dont understand the code. process need the parameter f but nothing is given in transform(process)? would you mind explaining what is happening?

Comment: @SomaJuice: I cannot explain really explain `groupby` and `transform` here. Better for you to look at official [Pandas doc.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html). Here `process` is applied to each *sub-series* from the change column.

Comment: okay thanks you very much for your help!